# Module not showing on Joomla page (regular menu item)

Tags: php, joomla, module

I have a Joomla template that does not show a module on one of my pages. The module is published and is assigned to a regular published menu item.

After doing some research I found that the issue may be due to template overides.  Here is my module.php file...is there anything in here that would cause a module not to show on a particular page?

Thanks,

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

function modChrome_themeHtml5($module, &$params, &$attribs) {
    $moduleTag      = $params->get('module_tag');
    $headerTag      = htmlspecialchars($params->get('header_tag'));
    $headerClass    = $params->get('header_class');
    $bootstrapSize  = $params->get('bootstrap_size');
    $moduleClass    = !empty($bootstrapSize) ? ' span' . (int) $bootstrapSize . '' : '';
    $moduleClassSfx = htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx'));

    if (!empty ($module->content)){
        $html  = "<{$moduleTag} class=\"moduletable {$moduleClassSfx} {$moduleClass}\">";

        if ((bool) $module->showtitle){
          $html .= "<{$headerTag} class=\"moduleTitle {$headerClass}\">{$module->title}     </{$headerTag}>";
        }

        $html .= $module->content;
        $html .= "</{$moduleTag}>";

        echo $html;
    }
}


function modChrome_html5nosize($module, &$params, &$attribs){
    $moduleTag      = $params->get('module_tag');
    $headerTag      = htmlspecialchars($params->get('header_tag'));
    $headerClass    = $params->get('header_class');
    $bootstrapSize  = $params->get('bootstrap_size');
  //$moduleClass    = !empty($bootstrapSize) ? ' span' . (int) $bootstrapSize . '' : '';
    $moduleClassSfx = htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx'));

    if (!empty ($module->content)){
        $html  = "<{$moduleTag} class=\"moduletable {$moduleClassSfx}\">";

        if ((bool) $module->showtitle){
          $html .= "<{$headerTag} class=\"moduleTitle {$headerClass}\">{$module->title}</{$headerTag}>";
        }

        $html .= $module->content;
        $html .= "</{$moduleTag}>";

        echo $html;
    }
}



function modChrome_modal($module, &$params, &$attribs){
    $moduleTag      = $params->get('module_tag');
    $headerTag      = htmlspecialchars($params->get('header_tag'));
    $headerClass    = $params->get('header_class');
    $bootstrapSize  = $params->get('bootstrap_size');
    // $moduleClass    = !empty($bootstrapSize) ? ' span' . (int) $bootstrapSize . '' : '';
    $moduleClassSfx = htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx'));

    if (!empty ($module->content)){
        $html = "<div class=\"modal fade moduletable {$moduleClassSfx} loginPopup\" id=\"modal\">";
        $html .= "<button type=\"button\" class=\"close modalClose\">×</button>";

        if ((bool) $module->showtitle){
            $html .= "<div class=\"modal-header\">";
            $html .= "<{$headerTag} class=\"{$headerClass}\">{$module->title}</{$headerTag}>";
            $html .= "</div>";
        }

        $html .= "<div class=\"modal-body\">";
        $html .= $module->content;
        $html .= "</div>";

        $html .= "</{$moduleTag}>";

        echo $html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be if `(!empty ($module->content))`

We can't be so sure from just looking at the code. Try debugging it yourself by commenting out the code inside functions part by part, and see from which function the problem is occurring. That's the easiest and fastest way.